# How to capture image from four cameras when you have only three usb ports in the laptop using C# and Emgucv?

Tags: c#, image, opencv, image-processing, emgucv

I am trying to get images from different cameras using capture class.
I have three ports in the laptop but i have to use four cameras or may be more . I am using a usb hub and connecting the camera with it but it isn't working.

```
Capture capture1 = new Capture(0);
    Capture capture2 = new Capture(1);
    Capture capture3 = new Capture(2);
    Capture capture4 = new Capture(3);
```

But it is giving an exception of Couldnot capture from camera 3 ! 
Please help.

Comment: do not use your platform/API for camera but Are you sure your cameras does not reach the USB bandwidth limit? when you use USB hub you divide the Bandwidth of that particular line. I had this problem in the past with old USB 1.1 ports they could handle 1 camera but not 2. Try to compute bandwith needed for all camera traffic. if exceeding used bandwith then use more then just 1 hub. Also it is dependent on which USB the HUBS will be placed ... (depending on the internal circuit ...) The same goes for power some Ports can supply 500mA and some only 100mA when divided it may be not enough

Comment: More than one hubs worked , thank you :)